# One month new hire, my boss left, what is the good and bad for me?

Tags: management

I am currently facing a scenario.

I am a new hire in a big company, just for one month. However, what astonished me today, is that my boss told us that he was going to leave after two weeks.

To old employees, I think their feeling can be mixed. Some of them who liked him, may feel bad, and for those who disliked him, may feel good.

But to me, I am neutral to this news: I haven't developed any relationship with him. However, I feel a little bit uncertainty. I don't know the future.

I would like to know, for a new hire like me, what is the good and bad, if my boss left the team？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably makes no difference at all to you. Another manager will be assigned to watch over your group. That person will probably be either better or worse than the one who is departing -- you don't know anyone well enough yet to even begin to guess, so the safe assumption is "the same" until there is evidence otherwise.

In any case, it will have very little effect on what you're currently doing, though it may become more significant later ... and there isn't anything you can or should be doing except to get to know the new manager and work with him and the rest of the department to address the company's needs.

Comment: One potential advantage is that the new manager may feel that there is less difference between new hires and older hands, since everyone has been around longer than him. Possible chance for a talented person to shine a little brighter than they might have if they were seen as "the new guy".